Map RGB colors from a heatmap back to their original scale values
I have the following heatmap

and all I know is that the mapping between the colors and the original values is as follows: -100 is blue, 0 is black, and +10 is red. The mapping is assumed to be linear. White squares can be ignored (i.e nan).
I have managed to extract the heatmap as an SVG (the one I'm showing here is a WEBP because stackoverflow does not allow SVG) and I therefore have the RGB color of each square.
How could I map each RBG color back to its original value, or at least a good approximation ?

What value corresponds to the white squares?

Something like this maybe? Make a ramp (a.k.a. gradient) from blue to black 100 pixels wide and 1 pixel tall. Make a ramp from black to red 10 pixels wide and 1 pixel tall. Append the second to the first so you have a ramp from blue through black to red. Use Numpy's linalg.norm() and subtract 100 from your nearest answer.

It doesn't help that the "blue" pixels in particular contain a lot of green and red. Can it be assumed that only the blue channel matters for -100 (blue 255) to 0 (all channels 0)?

@Wacton It is indeed unclear to me why even when extracting the RBG values from the SVG, the green channel is generally != 0, and the red and blue channels are != 0 in almost all cases. I do not know which library was used to generate the heatmap so I cannot check the library for available color scales to try to find a match. Regarding the idea of ignoring channels, I will try it, as it simplifies the problem greatly.

@MarkSetchell I'll give it a go

I like this kind of problem and made a library to help with it: https://github.com/scienxlab/unmap. It is designed to work with bitmaps, not SVG, but you will see that finding the nearest colour by Euclidean distance in RGB space will map your image to the 'codebook' (colour to value mapping). I will try to post an answer using the data you shared.
